# How do I set-constraints on a controller?

Tags: juju, openstack

What is the equivalent command for:

```
$ juju set-constraints tags=controller
```

in Juju 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will apply the constraint to a "model" instead of to the old concept of an "environment".

```
juju set-model-constraints -m [<controllername>:]<model name> tags=controller
```